# Google Drive apps scope broken

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm requesting the installed drive apps. This worked fine until yesterday.
Today I get:
{
  "code" : 401,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "location" : "Authorization",
    "locationType" : "header",
    "message" : "Invalid Credentials",
    "reason" : "authError"
  } ],
  "message" : "Invalid Credentials"
}
even though the scope is granted.
Any ideas?

Comment: Did you check if your access and refresh token are still valid? According this source (https://developers.google.com/drive/handle-errors#401_invalid_credentials), if you received that warning, it means that you have a problem with tokens.

Comment: Yes, I've created new tokens etc. but the error remains.
It worked like a charm yesterday :-(

Comment: Ok, finally got it. Maybe I'm crazy, but I could swear the "drive.app" scope worked yesterday - now it changed to "drive.app.readonly"

Comment: You aren't crazy, it changed - we didn't think anyone would be using it - sorry!. Out of interest, what are you using it for?

Comment: I'm using it for my app for the "Google Developer Challenge".
No more details yet ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the drive.app.readonly scope.